# How to get the length of a standardinput in C?

Tags: c

I will start with my code:

```
char input[40];
fgets( input, 40, stdin );
if( checkPalin(input) == 0 ) {
    printf("%s ist ein Palindrom \n", input);
}
else {
    printf("%s ist kein Palindrom \n", input);
}
```

What I want to do is: Read some standardinput and check with my function if it is a Palindrome or not.

My problems are the following:
How can I get the length of the standardinput? Because if it is larger then 40 chars I wanna put an errormessage and furthermore I want my char array to be the exact length of the actual input.

Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fgets( input, 40, stdin );`

length of input should not go beyond 40 characters == 39characters + nul character

If you give string having length more than 39 characters, then `fgets()` reads first 39 characters and place `nul character('\0')` as 40 character and ignores remaining characters.

If you give string less than 39 characters , for example 5 
then it places reads newline also 
length becomes 6(excluding nul character)

Do not forgot to remove newline character.

```
char input[60];
fgets(input,sizeof input,stdin);
```

For example if you declare input buffer size with some 60 then if you want to do error checking for more than 40 characters.

You can simply check with `strlen()` and check length is more than 40.then show error message

If you want to check error with `fgets()` check against  `NULL`

Answer (score 1):

With

`fgets( input, 40, stdin );`

`input` is guaranteed to have number of characters less than equal to 40 (null termination included)

You don't have to perform checks .

And for getting size of the `input` you can always use `strlen()` function on `input`, as the produced character string from `fgets` is always null terminated.

Comment: but if for example the stdin is like 45 charakters. In this case I don`t want to just get 40 chars and than cut, I want to put an error message. How can can I do that?

Comment: @JakobAbfalter then probably you need to write your own version of `fgets`, taken inputs as characters and form C string, if number of char increase than max size, display message. I also, won't suggest `gets`, because it is unsafe, vulnerable to buffer overflow

Answer (score 1):

There's no any function to do it, you need to write it yourself. I.e., read byte by byte looking for `EOF` character. But I guees you're doing it for avoid overflow, right? if input is larger than `40` characters, you don't need to because is guaranted such a extra values is not put into your buffer by `fgets()` function, it's **never** larger than the size you have requested: 40. The value may be less-than or equal, but never greater than.

**EDIT:**

By "How to get the lenght of a standardinput in C?" I was thinking that you're talking about how many bytes there's in `stdin`. I'm sorry for that. If you want to get how may bytes has `fgets()` written in, just use `strlen()`

Comment: The getline() function does exactly what OP needs, and is part of the POSIX standard since 2008.  See the link in my "potential duplicate" comment above.

Comment: But the OP has not mentioned your platform...

Answer (score 1):

It just turned out that it is not so easy to write a function which uses `fgets()` repeatedly in order to return a `malloc()`ed string.

The function does no proper error reporting: If there was an error using `realloc()` or `fgets()`, the data retrieved till now is returned.

Apart from these, the function proved quite usable.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char * read_one_line(FILE * in)
{
    size_t alloc_length = 64;
    size_t cumulength = 0;
    char * data = malloc(alloc_length);
    while (1) {
        char * cursor = data + cumulength; // here we continue.
        char * ret = fgets(cursor, alloc_length - cumulength, in);
        printf("r %p %p %zd %zd %zd\n", data, cursor, cumulength, alloc_length, alloc_length - cumulength);
        if (!ret) {
            // Suppose we had EOF, no error.
            // we just return what we read till now...
            // there is still a \0 at cursor, so we are fine.
            break;
        }
        size_t newlength = strlen(cursor); // how much is new?
        cumulength += newlength; // add it to what we have.
        if (cumulength < alloc_length - 1 || data[cumulength-1] == '\n') {
            // not used the whole buffer... so we are probably done.
            break;
        }
        // we need more!
        // At least, probably.
        size_t newlen = alloc_length * 2;
        char * r = realloc(data, newlen);
        printf("%zd\n", newlen);
        if (r) {
            data = r;
            alloc_length = newlen;
        } else {
            // realloc error. Return at least what we have...
            // TODO: or better free and return NULL?
            return data;
        }
    }
    char * r = realloc(data, cumulength + 1);
    printf("%zd\n", cumulength + 1);
    return r ? r : data; // shrinking should always have succeeded, but who knows?
}

int main()
{
    char * p = read_one_line(stdin);
    printf("%p\t%zd\t%zd\n", p, malloc_usable_size(p), strlen(p));
    printf("%s\n", p);
    free(p);
}
```